# Haskell & Scrypt: How to get the encrypted hash

Tags: haskell, scrypt, io-monad

*Sorry for the basic question, just started learning Haskell.

I am trying to write a function that will get a string and return an encrypted hash.

What I have come up with for the moment is:

```
encrypt :: ByteString -> ByteString
encrypt = do
    x <- Crypto.Scrypt.encryptPassIO' (Pass "secret")
    fmap Crypto.Scrypt.getEncryptedPass x
```

However I get the error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘ByteString’
              with actual type ‘IO ByteString’
• In a stmt of a 'do' block: x <- encryptPassIO' (Pass plain)
  In the expression:
    do { x <- encryptPassIO' (Pass plain);
         fmap Crypto.Scrypt.getEncryptedPass x }
  In an equation for ‘encrypt’:
      encrypt plain
        = do { x <- encryptPassIO' (Pass plain);
               fmap Crypto.Scrypt.getEncryptedPass x }
```

Any idea how I can get rid of the IO?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot get rid of IO (without using darkest magic, or by calling another library method). Rather, fix your type: `ByteString -> IO ByteString`

Comment: Oh... ok. How do I save the value to the database then? I.e. further down I have `execute "INSERT INTO test VALUES ...` that I want to use the encrypted value with.

Comment: If that further down the line is an `IO` operation as well, just put both of them in a `do` expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than getting rid of the `IO`, you need to adjust `encrypt` to return an `IO ByteString`. `encryptPassIO'` needs random data to use for the salt, which it gets from the `IO` monad, so you are stuck there.

```
import Crypto.Scrypt (encryptPassIO', getEncryptedPass)
encrypt :: ByteString -> IO ByteString
encrypt = fmap getEncryptedPass . encryptPassIO' . Pass
```

Instead of `do` notation, I've used `encryptPassIO' . Pass` to get the `IO EncryptedPass` value from the argument. We then use `fmap` to lift `getEncryptedPass :: EncryptedPass -> ByteString` into the `IO` monad.

You could use `do` notation, but IMO `fmap` makes this cleaner:

```
encrypt pass = do
    x <- encryptPassIO' pass
    return (getEncryptedPass x)
```